# Objects counters

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I would like to have to counters for each class type that that was ever instantiated. As a starting point someone sugested this approach as an example:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person() {
        objects.push_back(this);
    }
    virtual ~Person() {
        objects.erase(this);
    }

static void print_types()
{
    for (auto pers : container)
    {
        std::cout << typeid(*pers).name() << "\n";
    }
}
private:
    static std::set<const Person*> objects;
};

class Employee : public Person
{
};


class Employee2 : public Employee
{
};
```

Each time one of the classes is instatiated I keep track of the objects and I can use print_types() to know how many of which type I've created so far. Notice that Employee2 inherits from Employee and not from Person (i need this to work for chain inheritance)

I would like to extend this so that I have two counters per type: created and alive. The problem is that you can't easily mantain the counters from the constructor/destructor of the base class, Person, because typeid(*this) will return the base class type when called from constructor/destructor.

Another suggestion was to use CRTP pattern but this doesn't work when you use chained inheritance.

Is there another way to implement such counters ?

Comment: why do you want that? Maybe consider a object factory that keeps track of created objects. Smart pointers can be customized to have a deleter that does additional bookkeeping. Your current approach is rather invasive while a factory might work too and would also allow you to do bookkeeping for built in types as for example `int` or `double`

Comment: @user463035818 if I'm not mistaking, object factories can't track objects instantiated on the stack, only those that are created on the heap. I'll try to see if it's feasible to change the entire project so that objects are created only through an object factory.

Comment: Are you trying to find memory leak? If so use proper tool like valgrind or Dr memory

Comment: Why do you want to keep count? http://xyproblem.info

Comment: one thing why I would like to keep counters is that we're using external libraries and in case of memory leaks I would like to know if the memory leaks are caused by my code or the third party libraries. This approach will reduce debuging time. Also you can put a limit on the number of objects that can be alive

Comment: As mentioned above there are better ways to hunt down memleaks; also you simply can't count *every* pointer you're using. But consistently using smart pointers helps significantly avoiding them: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory

Comment: sure smart pointers are the solution for heap allocated objects. Imagine you have a recursive function that allocates objects on the stack and maybe you want to prevent it from recurring for ever (because of an unexpected input or corner case) until you run out of memory, one way to do this is to limit the number objects it cretes on the stack by counting them and throwing an exception after a threshold.

Comment: Another use case is when you alocate on the stack an object and after that you block the thread on waiting for a mutex and then another thread does the same thing blocking at same mutex and so on. And that mutex is nevere released.

Comment: Binding the locking of a mutex to the lifetime of an object (except it's a mutex locker) usually isn't a good idea. If possible you should keep mutex locks as short as possible (limited to the critical section), else you'll experience performance derogation. I admit that debugging multithreading issues is a pain, but this most surely isn't a remedy for it.

Comment: Indeed mutex is not the best example, you can replace the mutex by a condition variable or any I/O blocking call on which you wait and you'll have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just played around a bit. Maybe this helps you. It always prints the value of the right class (not the base class).

But it's practically the same^^.

Header:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

class observeable;
class observer
{
public:
  observer() = delete;
  static void print();
  static std::set< observeable* > items;
};

class observeable
{
public:
  observeable();
  virtual ~observeable();
  virtual std::string get_typeid();
};
```

Source:

```
std::set< observeable* > observer::items;

void observer::print()
{
  std::cout << "Called" << std::endl;
  for( auto item : items )
    std::cout << item->get_typeid() << std::endl;
}

observeable::observeable()
{
  observer::items.insert( this );
}

observeable::~observeable()
{
  observer::items.erase( this );
}

std::string observeable::get_typeid()
{
  return std::string( typeid(*this).name() );
}
```

Main:

```
#include <memory>

class A : observeable
{};

class B : A
{};

class C : observeable 
{};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  observer::print(); // A B present

  {
    C d;
  }
  observer::print(); // no C present

  auto d_heap = std::shared_ptr<C>( new C() );
  observer::print(); // C present
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is working if you don't need to keep objects counters. What I mean is that you would need to know the type at the creation, when the constructor of observeable is called, so that you can increment the correct counter for the correct type.

Comment: But with this trick at hand you could implement the count for any derived class, by sorting out the objects of the appropriate type from the object list at the moment you're counting.

Comment: You're right, someone has to call the counting method once in a while, this can be a solution. I was more interested if it was possible to do the counting at creation time and not at counting time.